# Mean values of position in Van der Waals coupled systems

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm trying to solve a problem regarding two systems interacting through a coupling hamiltonian:
$$ H(x,y) = H_1(x) + H_2(y) + kxy $$
I am supposed to express the mean values $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ in terms of their independent momenta $\langle x^n \rangle _0 = \int dx \rho_1(x) x^n$ (and the same for y), which are calculated on the isolated systems. It is not specified in the text of the exercise but I'm assuming to be in the canonical ensemble.$$$$
My idea was to find an expression of the momenta by manipulating the integral for the expectation value:
$$\langle x \rangle = \frac{1}{Z}\int d\Gamma x\cdot\rho$$
Where i suppose $\rho = \frac{Z_1Z_2}{Z} \rho_1\rho_2e^{-\beta kxy}$. So I tried to separate the integral with respect to the two variables and noted that maybe I could use the fact that $xe^{-\beta kxy} = -\frac{1}{\beta k}\frac{\partial }{\partial y} e^{-\beta kxy}$ to integrate with respect to y and get to:
$$\langle x\rangle = \frac{Z_1Z_2}{Z\beta k}\int d\Gamma_1 \rho_1 e^{-\beta kxy}$$
But from here I have no idea on how to proceed, how to write this in term of the independent moment of x as it's asked. In fact I am not even sure that what I did so far is correct.

EDIT: What I did is surely not correct, as I have integrated over y discarding the fact that the density function was in the integral, too. So I tried to integrate by parts, but that just gave me a term:
$$\int d\Gamma_2 \dot{p_y} e^{-\beta kxy}e^{-\beta H_2}$$
The other term of the integration by parts I supposed to be $0$ as it is:
$$(e^{-\beta (kxy + H_2)})_{y= \pm \infty}$$
So now I'm kind of back where I started..